# Not able to install Ionic on windows 8.1

Tags: npm, ionic-framework

After i update node 0.12.5 i was getting node_module error and since after i am not able to install ionic.
After google it was recommended that ionic is not supporting latest node version.
I uninstall and install older version of node 0.10.33 but not able to fix the problem since four days.
every time I get error fail fetch from registry
I include the following line in npmrc

registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
strict-ssl=false
ca=

but futile

still proxy setting is not proper that yet to be resolve.